# Java ImageIO.read lets something hanging...

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Im transforming a byte[] of a image to a jpg with defined width and height and store that image on my amazon s3, however I just detected that something on java is getting 'hanging' just after the line when I use the ImageIO.read instruction. I only notice it because the java console opens when the ImageIO.read line is hit, but never closes until I close my app. I have checked to close all the buffers and streams that I found in my code but the console remains opens even after the image was saved on amazon. is there a way to check what is going on?  I have been reading on stackoverflow that ImageIO.read have some memory leak problems.

here is my code:

```
private byte[]  transformImageToJpg(byte[] receivedImage, int width, int height) {
    if (receivedImage == null)
        return null;

    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
    byte[] imageInByte = null;
    try {
         is = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivedImage);
        bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(is);
        if(bufferedImage == null) {
            receivedImage = null;
            is.close();
            showError("Invalid File", "The selected file is not a valid image file.");
            return null;
        }

        int w = bufferedImage.getWidth();
        int h = bufferedImage.getHeight();
        BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width,
                height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        newBufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, w, h, Color.WHITE, null);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(newBufferedImage, "jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        newBufferedImage.flush();
        bufferedImage.flush();
        baos.close();
        is.close();
        receivedImage = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageInByte;
}
```

Comment: What is displayed in* the Java console? It doesn't just open for no reason.

Comment: I don't know it just open up, but I can't open the console window, Its a process that is going on on the back, how ever I used jvisualvm to check my app threads and  found out that maybe the guilty is a thread called AWT-AppKit, this thread start after I call the method 'transformImageToJpg()', but never stop, just keep going, Im going to read more about it.

Comment: @user2171127 That actually makes sense, I was about to suggest it but had no time during work hours. Because `BufferedImage` inherits `Image` which has some native AWT initialization in its static initializer, it's very likely that loading this class is the cause (it starts the AWT native machinery). Most likely you can avoid it by [running your program in headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) (setting the `java.awt.headless` system property to `true`). If you don't use AWT or Swing obviously...